# SQL Error In Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

`INSERT` statement,

```
INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`access`) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

Im getting this error

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1

Any Ideas on how I might fix this?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`access`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
prepState = DBconnection.prepareStatement(sql);
prepState.setInt(1, newIdNum);
prepState.setString(2, addedUsername);
prepState.setString(3, addedPassword);
prepState.setString(4, addedAccess);
prepState.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Im trying to do this in java

Comment: can you give codes other than that? maybe the whole block of code because the paramertized `INSERT` statement is very fine.

Comment: pleasegive some code in which you are binding the query.. I hope you are doing that

Comment: In general, it is NOT necessary to quote column and table names.  I suggest that you not use quotes unless you have a specific case where you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you are not `BINDing` the values to that SQL, which means your question marks are not being replaced.  See the question marks in error message? `?,?,?,?)`

Comment: Edited my original post